# Load checked checkboxes from db

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox

I have a jsp page with list of application names with check boxes to each applications, and there is save button also.

What I need to achieve is that, I need to save these checked value in db and upon loading the jsp page again, I need all the preciously checked application as checked and the rest without checking.

Is there any way to get the stored checked values and check the check boxes while  displaying all the applications.

In detail below is my application list with check boxes

☑ Java
☑ Python
☑ C
☐ C++
☐ Rails
☐ ASP

in this list I have selected only first three items and these are stored with my `userid` in db as given below

anand -> Java
anand -> Python
anand -> C

Now upon loading this application page again, these three items in db should be checked and others should remain unchecked.

Can any one help?

Comment: just compare the list item to the database item and set the isSelected property to true

Comment: Yep , you need to have a javascript part , probably ajax , that asks the server(your db) what is checked for each user and then changes the html property accordingly . To get more specific you'll have to provide us with your code!

Comment: My code is too long to paste here, can you give any sample example or give a tip on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a db there are tons of tutorials around the web: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630275/how-to-get-data-from-a-database-to-a-jsp-page-in-java

When you have your checked values stored in variables (let's say one for each checkbox) you just add this code to your html:

```
boolean java =//contains the value from the db
String javaChecked="";
if(java==true){
    javaChecked="checked='checked'";
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="java" <%= javaChecked %>>
```